# Debugging issue with find command on linux

Tags: linux, jboss

I am running JBoss EAP6 on two servers and I am trying to get CAS working. It works on node 1 great but on node 2 I am getting a error:

```
Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path
```

If I run the following on node 1:

find / -name log4j-over-slf4j.jar 2>errors.txt I

get this output:

```
/usr/share/java/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j.jar 
/usr/share/java/slf4j-eap6/log4j-over-slf4j.jar
```

But if I run it on node 2 I get the following:

```
/usr/share/java/slf4j-eap6/log4j-over-slf4j.jar 
/usr/share/java/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j.jar
```

if I run: 
find / -name slf4j-log4j12.jar 2>errors.txt

is at /usr/share/java/slf4j-eap6/slf4j-log4j12.jar on both nodes.

I have a feeling that node2 is using /usr/share/java/slf4j-eap6/ before /usr/share/java/slf4j/ which has both jars in them making the error.. Keep in mind node 1 works..

Comment: sounds less like a `find` error, and more like a jBoss CLASSPATH issue to me.  I'm no jBoss guru, but I'd wager you can add directories to the app server's classpath; and that would be where I'd look first.

Comment: i think you are right but why would FIND find them in two diff orders

Comment: [See this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/181787/find-command-default-sorting-order).  TL;DR version:  find returns results in the order it finds them; which is determined by their position within the file system.  Operating systems can move them around if they want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe (I cannot be sure in this case as there can be other causes) the two servers have different locale setting, which can affect sort order.

To check system locale setting, run `locale`.

PS: Maybe comment from Gus above is more accurate. However I cannot find additional documentation to support either case.